# Angular2 - Persistent service between components on different levels

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

Ive been wrestling with this for most of the day. basically my applications layout is like so

```
app.component.ts
  -- navigation.component.ts : i.e this selector is in the app.component
  -- router-outlet
```

Basically the navigation bar is where I have all my login logic, I am using Firebase and this is were the magic happens, users login and their image is in the top right and their name etc.. its all lovely. My problem is that I would like to share this data with other components. Now after some helpful advice on here earlier I setup a service that passed the data from the nav component to one of the other components that displays, this is a dynamic component, meaning when you click a link it loads dynamically while the nav component stays static as its on the same level as the router outlet. so with my service when you first visit the page the data appears no problem, I imagine this is because the constructor fires once and everything works as expected, but when you navigate back.. nothing.. no user data passes to this component, and because the nav component doest ever do an ngOnInit except for when the site first loads if your on that very route.. I hope I have done a good job of explaining this, I am relatively new to angular2 so still learning..  Somethings that come into my head is maybe is this something that can be achieved somehow with more advanced observables or event emitters maybe ??

SERVICE.TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

// https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

@Injectable()
export class UserdataService {
  // Observable string sources
  private shareUserDataSRC = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  userDataAvailable$ = this.shareUserDataSRC.asObservable();


  passUserToService(userdata: string) {
    this.shareUserDataSRC.next(userdata);
    console.log(" service " + userdata);
  }


}
```

NAVIGATION.TS

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { UserdataService }     from '../userdata.service';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    template: `
            <header class="mast-head">
                <ul class="list-reset logged-in">
                    <li class="user-welcome">
                        <span>Hi, </span>
                        <a class="go-to-profile" href="#">{{ user?.name }}</a>
                        <i class="open-options"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </header>

            <aside class="side-drawer">

            </aside>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
    })
    export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit  {

    user      = {};

    constructor(  private router: Router, private shareUser: UserdataService) {

    }


    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.user);
    }


        private _changeState(user: any = null) {
        if(user) {
        this.user      = this._getUserInfo(user)
        } else {
        this.user      = {};
        }
    }

    private _getUserInfo( user: any ): any {

        if(!user) {
        return {};
        }

        let data     = user.auth.providerData[0];

        this.shareUser.passUserToService(data);

        return {
        name: data.displayName,
        avatar: data.photoURL,
        email: data.email,
        provider: data.providerId
        };

    }

    private _getProvider( from: string ) {
        ...STUFF GOING ON HERE...
    }

    }
```

TEMPLATE-I-WANT-TO-DISPLAY.TS

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { AdInterface} from '../interfaces';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { UserdataService }     from '../userdata.service';
    import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-list-adverts',
    template: `
                <h2 class="timestamp">
                {{ announced?.uid }}
                {{ announced?.displayName }}
                {{ announced?.photoURL }}
                {{ announced?.email }}      
                {{ announced?.providerId }}                                                        
                </h2>
    `
    })

    export class ListAdvertsComponent implements OnInit {

        subscription: any;
        announced: string;
        userServ: any;

        constructor( private router: Router, private shareUser: UserdataService ) { 
                        this.userServ = this.shareUser.userDataAvailable$;
                        this.subscription = this.userServ.subscribe(userdata => {
                            this.announced = userdata;
                            // console.log( JSON.stringify(this.announced) );
                        });
                    }


        ngOnInit() {
        }

        ngOnDestroy() {
            // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular has a perfect dependency injection system which might be helpful to solve your problem.

I assume that you're providing the UserdataService in some of your feature modules in your application. Try to provide it on AppModule:

```
import { UserdataServce } from './path/to/service.ts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        ...
        UserdataService,
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This way you can make sure your components can now get the same instance of UserdataService.